# Is there setwidth is in NSString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, nsstring

I want to append my string with fixed-width spaces; for example, I want to show the data in this format:

```
1   faizan   1    locked    10/20/2008
1   faizan   1    locked    10/20/2008
1   faizan   1    locked    10/20/2008
1   faizan   1    locked    10/20/2008
```

But this only works with strings of the same length. If the strings are different like this:

```
1   faizan   1    locked    10/20/2008
2   faizanali   1    locked    10/20/2008
3   ali turab gilani    1    locked    10/20/2008
```

then this doesn't fix the spaces. So that I can show the data in with the same number of spaces, I tried this:

```
NSString *titleColumn = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:", title] stringByPaddingToLength:20 withString:@" " startingAtIndex:0];
serializedValue = [serializedValue stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@%@", titleColumn, value];
```

But this also didn't work. Does Objective-C have a `setwidth`-type function like in C++ and in other languages?

Comment: How many strings you have to display

Comment: i want to append 5 strings and there is 30 rows of that type of string

Comment: How exactly didn't `stringByPaddingToLength:` work for you? This is actually the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Are you doing it in this way?

**/* Define a helper method */**

```
- (NSString *)formattedStringWithStrings:(NSArray *)strings {

    NSString *str1 = [[strings objectAtIndex:0] stringByPaddingToLength:3 withString:@" " startingAtIndex:0];
    NSString *str2 = [[strings objectAtIndex:1] stringByPaddingToLength:20 withString:@" " startingAtIndex:0];
    NSString *str3 = [[strings objectAtIndex:2] stringByPaddingToLength:3 withString:@" " startingAtIndex:0];
    NSString *str4 = [[strings objectAtIndex:3] stringByPaddingToLength:10 withString:@" " startingAtIndex:0];
    NSString *str5 = [[strings objectAtIndex:4] stringByPaddingToLength:15 withString:@" " startingAtIndex:0];
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@%@", str1, str2, str3, str4, str5]; 
}
```

**/* Use the helper method */**

```
NSArray *strings = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"faizan", @"1", @"locked", @"10/20/2008", nil];
NSLog(@"%@", [self formattedStringWithStrings:strings]);

strings = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"2", @"faizanali", @"1", @"locked", @"10/20/2008", nil];
NSLog(@"%@", [self formattedStringWithStrings:strings]);

strings = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"3", @"ali turab gilani", @"1", @"locked", @"10/20/2008", nil];
NSLog(@"%@", [self formattedStringWithStrings:strings]);
```

**/* And the output */**

```
1  faizan              1  locked    10/20/2008
2  faizanali           1  locked    10/20/2008
3  ali turab gilani    1  locked    10/20/2008
```

Comment: coooollllll maannnnn that is awesome if this work fine i will try it and then tell you but this is awesome way to solve

Comment: hi i tried you example it worked fine for the console out put but when i put that text in 
    cell.textLabel.text = [RanksInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
then it is again lose some spaces how can i solve that

Comment: Yes. That depends on the font you use. Most of the fonts use different width with for different characters. Try using Courier font, `lbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"CourierNewPSMT" size:16];`. This uses same width for all the characters and the text is perfectly aligned.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `NSMutableString` to implement this. The logic is:

1. Check the maximum length string, say `maxLength`.
2. Now run a for loop to iterate all strings and append the string with " " (white space) if the current length of the string is less than the `maxLength`.
3. Now with final result you will get all strings with same length.

Comment: nice logic man liked it but that is not the proper way to solve such thing is there is no built in function for that to solve this problem like setwidth in c++